# MySQL is duplicating GROUP_CONCAT content in one of the rows

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

- store_cat: categories
- store_cat_attribute: attributes for each category
- store_item: items which are optionally linked to a category

I need a query that returns rows that contain these columns:

- Category: Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
- Item COUNT

This is my current query, which works almost fine:

```
SELECT store_cat.id_cat AS id,
CONCAT(store_cat.name, IFNULL(CONCAT(": ", GROUP_CONCAT(store_cat_attribute.name ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position SEPARATOR ", "), ""), "")) AS name,
COUNT(DISTINCT store_item.id_item) AS products
FROM store_cat
LEFT JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
WHERE store_cat.id_store = 1
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat
ORDER BY name
```

The problem is that in one of the rows, oddly enough, the `name` column is duplicating the attributes in the `GROUP_CONCAT`:

**Category**: Attribute1, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute3

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve it? Thanks!

Here you can check the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da2d3/5

Comment: Yes JOIN's can duplicate/multiply data results for aggregated functions, i think `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT store_cat_attribute.name` should fix it.

Comment: Also your SQL is not using GROUP BY correct see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da2d3/28)

Comment: @RaymondNijland adding DISTINCT inside the GROUP_CONCAT function didn't fix it :(

Comment: @RaymondNijland `store_cat.name` is functionally dependent on `store_cat.id_cat` - So it would work in MySQL 5.7. On the other side - you cant do `DISTINCT store_cat_attribute.name ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position`, because `store_cat_attribute.position` is not functionally dependent on `store_cat_attribute.name` - So it should fail on 5.7 - `name should be UNIQUE NOT NULL` in this case.

Comment: Well @PaulSpiegel `GROUP_CONCAT` is a aggregated function which is lose from `GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat` so you should be able to  do `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT store_cat_attribute.name ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position)` just fine.. i believe `GROUP_CONCAT` was called the poor mans MySQL's window function...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm not getting your point. How can you do `ORDER BY position` when there can be multiple diffrent values for each (DISTINCT) `name`? Consider theese entries: `(name, position) VALUES ('A', 1), ('A', 999)` - What will you use for ORDER BY - `1` or `999`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i think i misunderstood your comments then.. I readed that `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT store_cat_attribute.name ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position)` was not possible to use because you said `store_cat_attribute.position` is not functionally dependent on `store_cat_attribute.name`..  consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1dFX3ZRXtY17GV17Qic83/0) which is the same structure that i was talking about `GROUP_CONCAT` seams to be working as a cheap "window function" here.. And yes i was indeed wrong about the `DISTINCT` will not work with the data here.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well you've just found a bug. The query should fail (IMHO), because the result is non deterministic. Changing the insertion order will change the result: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bDwxkw7nqQnXNB13kLzmTG/0

Comment: Indeed @PaulSpiegel the `DISTINCT t.name
     ORDER BY position ASC` runs like `SELECT DISTINCT t.name FROM t 
     ORDER BY position ASC` offcource so indeed it should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating two different things in same query (the `GROUP_CONCAT` and the `COUNT`). The `JOIN` to `store_item` will cause the duplicates. You can move to the one into the select column:

```
SELECT 
  store_cat.id_cat AS id, 
  CONCAT(store_cat.name, IFNULL(CONCAT(": ", 
    GROUP_CONCAT( 
       store_cat_attribute.name 
      ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position 
      SEPARATOR ", "
    ), ""
    ), ""
   )) AS name, 
   (select count(distinct store_item.id_item) from store_item where store_item.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat) AS products 
FROM store_cat 
  LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
WHERE store_cat.id_store = 1 
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat, store_cat.name
ORDER BY name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da2d3/36

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks!